# How to use Lombok to create a constructor that calls AllArgsConstructor of super class?

Tags: java, constructor, javabeans, lombok, pojo

I have a super class and child class:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Parent {

    private String name;

}
```

```
@Data
public class Child extends Parent {

    private int age;

    // I want Lombok to create an equivalent constructor.
    public Child(String name, int age) {
        super(name);
        this.age = age;
    }

}
```

How can I use Lombok annotation to help me create child class constructor?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Did it cause a issue if you remove constructor inside child class?

Comment: @YJR: Yes, it says there is no default constructor available in 'Parent'.

Comment: I checked how I implemented. I implemented same  way as you. I think no other way to do that using lambok.

Comment: If there is a way I also want to know that.Therefore I upvote the question.

Answer (score 4):

As of lombok version `1.18.2` you can use for this reason the `@SuperBuilder` annotation.

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
public class Parent {

    private String name;

}
@Data
@SuperBuilder
public class Child extends Parent {

    private int age;
}
```

Keep in mind that the  annotation needs to be both in parent and in child class.

Then you can use it as `Child child = Child.builder().age(1).name("Mike").build()`

As written in the doc

> @SuperBuilder generates a protected constructor on the class that
> takes a builder instance as a parameter. This constructor sets the
> fields of the new instance to the values from the builder.

Official [documentation](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/SuperBuilder)

As explained in the documentation this does not exactly generate what the question asks,

```
          public Child(String name, int age) {
            super(name);
            this.age = age;
        }
```

But it creates instead a constructor that takes a builder as parameter and from this builder and the parameters it contains it moves forward to instantiating both fields in parent and child class. But this is the only possible solution with lombok as to use a constructor from the child class to instantiate fields both in parent and child class.

Keep in mind that this was added as an experimental feature 4 years ago and it still part of lombok.

Comment: Thank you for your solution, but I want to have the same constructor as above. I'm writing them manually now, and when I have time I'll consider raising an issue or writing an extension based on Lombok (I'm not sure if this is possible).

Comment: Don't bother creating am issue. This had been asked several times, and the answer is always: not possible. It's a technical limitation that Lombok cannot work around at the moment. `@SuperBuilder` is the only automatic way.